# Pass PIL Image to google cloud vision without saving and reading

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-vision

***UPDATE BELOW***

Is there a way to pass a PIL Image to google cloud vision?

I tried to use `io.Bytes`, `io.String` and `Image.tobytes()` but I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  "C:\Users\...\vision_api.py", line 20, in get_text
    image = vision.Image(content)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\proto\message.py", line 494, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid constructor input for Image:b'Ma\x81Ma\x81La\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81La\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x80Ma\x81La\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x80Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x81Ma\x8 ...
```

or this if I pass the PIL-Image directly:

```
TypeError: Invalid constructor input for Image: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=480x300 at 0x1D707131DC0>
```

This is my code:

```
image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')   # Opening the saved image
cropped_image = image.crop((30, 900, 510, 1200))   # Cropping the image

vision_image = vision.Image(# I passed the different options)   # Here I need to pass the image, but I don't know how
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
response = client.text_detection(image=vision_image)   # Text detection using google-vision-api
```

**FOR CLARITY:**

I want google text detection to only analyse a certain part of an image saved on my disk. So my idea was to crop the image using PIL and then pass the cropped image to google-vision. But it is not possible to pass an PIL-Image to `vision.Image`, as I get the error above.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries) from Google.

This can be found in the `vision.Image` class:

```
Attributes:
        content (bytes):
            Image content, represented as a stream of bytes. Note: As
            with all ``bytes`` fields, protobuffers use a pure binary
            representation, whereas JSON representations use base64.

            Currently, this field only works for BatchAnnotateImages
            requests. It does not work for AsyncBatchAnnotateImages
            requests.
```

A working option is to save the PIL-Image as a PNG/JPG on my disk and load it using:

```
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

vision_image = vision.Image(content=content)
```

But this is slow and seems unnecessary. And the whole point for me behind using google-vision-api is the speed comaped to open-cv.

**UPDATE as of 25/9/2021**

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from google.cloud import vision


with open('images/screenshots/screenshot.png', 'rb') as image_file:
    data = image_file.read()
    try:
        image = vision.Image(content=data)
        print('worked')

    except TypeError:
        print('failed')


im = Image.open('images/screenshots/screenshot.png')
buffer = BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, format='PNG')
try:
    image = vision.Image(buffer.getvalue())
    print('worked')

except TypeError:
    print('failed')
```

The first version works as expected, but I can't get the second one to work as @Mark Setchell recommended. The first few characters (~50) are the same, the rest is completely different.

**UPDATE as of 26/9/2021**

Both inputs are of type `<class 'bytes'>`. The complete error stack can be seen at the top of the question.

Using this code:

```
print(input_data[:200])
print(type(input_data))
```

i get the following output:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x048\x00\x00\x07\x80\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00+a\xe7\n\x00\x00\x00\x04sBIT\x08\x08\x08\x08|\x08d\x88\x00\x00 \x00IDATx\x9c\xec\xbdy\xd8-\xc7Y\x1f\xf8\xab\xea>\xe7\xdb\xef\xaa\xbbk\xb3%\xcb\x8b\x16[\x12\xc6\xc8\xbb,\x1b\x03\x06\xc6\x8111\x93@2y\xc2381\x8b1\x90\x10\x9e\xf18\x93\x10\x0811\x84\x192\x0c3\x9e\x1020\x03\x03\xc3\xb0\x04\xf0C0\xc6\x96m\xc9\x96m\xed\xb2dI\x96\xaetu\xf7\xed\xdb\xcf\xe9\xae\x9a?j\xe9\xea\xbd\xba\xbb\xbaO\x9f\xef\x9e\xd7\xd6\xfd\xfat\xbf\xf5Vu-o\xbd\xf5\xeb\xb7\xde"\xef\xff\xc7\'8\x1c\x13\x07\x00\xd2\x82\xcc6\xe5\xc6\xa8B&'
<class 'bytes'>
```

for the working input.
And:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x048\x00\x00\x07\x80\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00+a\xe7\n\x00\x01\x00\x00IDATx\x9c\xec\xbdw\x80$\xc7u\x1f\xfc\xab\xea\xeeI\x9bw/\'\x1cr\xce\x04@\x10\x04A\x82`\x84\x95%J"\x95,\xcb\x1f%\x91T\xb0$*}\x1fM\xd9\x96\x95EY\x94(\xc9\xb6\x92i+\x90\x12\x83(3)0\x82\x08$rN\x07\\\xce\xb7\xb7yBw\xd5\xf7G\x85\xaeN3\xdd=\xdd\xb3\xb3{\xfb\xc8\xc3\xceLW\xbd\xca\xaf\xde\xfb\xf5\xabW\xe4{\xdeu\x84\xa3`\xe2\x00@J\xe0Y&\xdf\x00e($\x94\x94\'p\xcc\xc3\xda\xe7Y\x0c\xf1Te\x13\xbf\xcc>\xfa:]Y=x\x84\x7f\xe8\xc23u\x1f\x91l\xfd\x99'
<class 'bytes'>
```

for the failing input.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you actually have? A file on disk? A Numpy array? A `PIL Image`? And what do you actually want? A PNG still compressed in memory? A base64 string? A Numpy array?

Comment: I have got a PIL Image. And I want to pass it to the google-cloud-vision. Since the documentation is very unclear i am unsure, ho wo passs it. What works is: Saving the PIL Image and then reading it again using the recommended way by google. But this is slow and and seems unnecessary. So my question is: How to modify the PIL Image, so it can be passed to google-cloud-vision

Comment: I do not use Google Vision API, and there seem to be several Python bindings and multiple, incompatible versions. Could you please be more specific about **exactly** what you are trying to call and also provide a link to the currently applicable documentation for it? Thank you. It would be best if you click `edit` under your question and put the details in there, correctly formatted, and not in the `comment` area.

Comment: I tried to clarify my problem. If you need any further clarification, let me know. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you start off with a `PIL Image` and you want to obtain a PNG image in memory without going to disk. So you need this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Create PIL Image like you have - filled with red
im = Image.new('RGB', (320,240), (255,0,0))

# Create in-memory PNG - like you want for Google Cloud Vision
buffer = BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, format="PNG")

# Look at first few bytes
PNG = buffer.getvalue()
print(PNG[:20])
```

It prints this, which is exactly what you would get if you wrote the image to disk as a PNG and then read it back as binary - except this does it in memory without going to disk:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01@'
```

Comment: If i open the image without with mode 'r', i get your result. But the image has to be read in mode 'rb'. How do I achieve that in memory?

Comment: It is correct. It is binary - it is just the way it is displayed.

Comment: Apparently it isn't the same as I still get a type error. See my updated Question. @Mark Setchell

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly get a type error - your code passes a PNG image, my code passes a PNG image. Both are of type `bytes` with similar content. Please share the full error stack, and for the sake of clarity print the types of the two things you pass to Google vision immediately prior to passing them. Thank you.

Comment: I tried my best to further clarify my problem. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I just resolved my problem. I was missing a `content=` in your version, so it passed the bytes as the wrong parameter. Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to have whole error stack and more accurate code snippet.  But form presented information this seems to be confusion of two different "Images". Probably the some copy/paste error, as  the [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detect_text_in_a_local_image) have exactly the same line:

```
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
```

But mentioned tutorials `image` is created by `vision.Image()` so I think in presented code this should be:

```
response = client.text_detection(image=vision_image)
```

As, at least if I understand correctly the code snippet, `image` is PIL Image, while `vision_image` is Vision Image that should be passed to `text_detection` method. So whatever is done in `vision.Image()` does not have effect on the error massage.

Comment: You are right, that was a typo in my stackoverflow question. But the exception is thrown before when creating the vision_image.